# How do you author an Azure VM extension?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

The internet seems to be void of information about authoring Azure VM extensions.  Certain classifications of companies (e.g. antivirus) seem to all have their own custom extensions.  Is the process of authoring these extensions secret?  If you pull down an existing extension or look at one of the open source linux VM extensions you will find that they are ridiculously simple.